# Hide taxonomy from side panel

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anybody know how to hide a custom taxonomy from under the post type? 
I have tried the following. 

`'public' => false
'show_ui' => false`

While I can remove both with the above I cannot remove just the sidebar taxonomy. I want the taxonomy to be available when adding a new post just removed from the sidebar. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: thats wierd, the `'show_ui' => false` removes sibebar taxonomy for me. so how are you showing the taxonomy in post editor (acf?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
  register_taxonomy("your-taxonomy", array("your-post-type"), array(
        "hierarchical" => true, 
        "label" => "Taxonomy Title", 
        "singular_label" => "Taxonomy", 
        'show_ui' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        "rewrite" => array('slug' => 'your-taxonomy')
    ));
```